# How to display average from list using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I just want to show their average from the list when the user stored a value in the list

But I try to use document.write(); but it's doesn't work for me

I want to show the average below the list

```
function listtable()
       {
            var score;
            var scoreArray = [];
            var scoreOutput; 
            var slenght; 
            var sum = 0;

            do
            {
                score = prompt("Please enter score and Enter -1 to stop 
                        entering");
                score = parseInt(score);
                if (score >=0 )
                {
                    scoreArray[scoreArray.length] = score;
                }
            } while (score != -1);

                scoreOutput = "<ul>";

                for (i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++) 
                {
                   scoreOutput += "<li>" + scoreArray[i] + "</li>";
                }

                scoreOutput += "</ul>";

                for (i = 0; i < scoreArray.Length; i++) 
                {
                    sum += parseInt(score[i]);
                }
                var avarage = sum/scoreArray.length;


                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = scoreOutput;
                document.write("The Avarage Score is: "   + average); 
       }
```

Comment: What exactly is not working right now?

Comment: Show your code related to `document.write();` where you want to print average value

Comment: when I put  document.write("The Avarage Score is: "   + avarage); . The result is 0

Comment: I already edit my code in the question

Comment: Did you try with reduce ? More efficient

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issue in your code,

1. You need to store elements in an array with incremental counter instead of storing it in an array length i.e Intested of `scoreArray[scoreArray.length] = score;` you need to store value at particular index.

Like.

```
    var index = 0;
    do
    {
        score = prompt("Please enter score and Enter -1 to stop 
                entering");
        score = parseInt(score);
        if (score >=0 )
        {
            scoreArray[index++] = score; 
                     //Use index with incremental operator
        }
    } while (score != -1);
```

---

2. While calculating sum you need to read value from `scoreArray` not from `score`. In your code `scoreArray` is an array **not** score variable.

correct code,

```
  for (i = 0; i < scoreArray.Length; i++) 
  {
      sum += parseInt(scoreArray[i]);
                    //Use scoreArray instead of score
  }
```

---

Now calculate average and print in HTML DOM

Like,

```
document.write("The Avarage Score is: " + avg);
```

Here is sample piece of code to print average.

```js
//Declaration of variables
var scoreArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var i, index = 0, sum = 0;

//Calculate sum
for(i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++)
   sum += scoreArray[i];

//Calculate average
var avg = sum/scoreArray.length;

document.write("The Avarage Score is: " + avg);
```

Comment: @DRGN, I updated my answer kindly look into it. I am updating my code with working piece of sample.

Comment: what if i'm still gonna use document.write()?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of typos in your code:

- `parseInt(score[i])` should be `parseInt(scoreArray[i])`
- `i < scoreArray.Length` should be `scoreArray.length` with a lowercase `l`
- The variable should be `average` not `avarage`

```js
function listtable() {
  var score;
  var scoreArray = [];
  var scoreOutput;
  var slenght;
  var sum = 0;

  do {
    score = prompt("Please enter score and Enter -1 to stop  entering ");
    score = parseInt(score);
    if (score >= 0) {
      scoreArray[scoreArray.length] = score;
    }
  }
  while (score != -1);

  scoreOutput = "<ul>";

  for (i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++) {
    scoreOutput += "<li>" + scoreArray[i] + "</li>";
  }

  scoreOutput += "</ul>";

  for (i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(scoreArray[i]);
  }
  
  var average = sum / scoreArray.length;

  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = scoreOutput;
  document.write("The Avarage Score is: " + average);
}

listtable()
```

```html
<span id="display" />
```

(Please search how to debug javascript code using `degbugger;` and dev tools. You can avoid trivial errors)

Comment: why i just see only the average and not the list of value?

Comment: It's working in the snippet. Click on *"Run Code Snippet"* to test it out. Do you have an element with `id="display"` in your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function listtable() {
    var score;
    var scoreArray = [];
    var scoreOutput; 
    var slenght; 
    var sum = 0;
    var i;

    do {
        score = prompt("Please enter score and Enter -1 to stop  entering");
        score = parseInt(score);
        if (score >=0 ) {
            scoreArray[scoreArray.length] = score;
        }
    } while (score != -1);

    scoreOutput = "<ul>";

    for (i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++) {
        console.log(scoreArray[i])
        sum += parseInt(scoreArray[i]);
        scoreOutput += "<li>" + scoreArray[i] + "</li>";
    }

    scoreOutput += "</ul>";

    var average = sum / scoreArray.length;

    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = scoreOutput;
    document.write("The Average Score is: "   + average); 
}

listtable();
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```

I have made the following changes in your code:

1. You have used 2 `for` loop which is not needed, I have added the code in the single `for` loop. (Optimized, Not an issue)
2. The variable name is defined as `average` but you used `avarage` in the `document.write`.
3. You didn't define the var `i` in your code and directly initializing it in the loop.

Comment: why i just see only the average and not the list of value?

Comment: @DRGN I am seeing the list of values as shown in the screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjk9E.png

Comment: @DRGN Use `Run code snippet` button and check the result as shown in the screenshot.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjk9E.png